# Why isn't my second tag type working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

ROR rookie. I'm using the acts_as_taggle_on gem for tagging, and tried to create two different types of tags, similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469143/how-to-apply-tags-with-acts-as-taggable-on-using-check-boxes). I've got the form working, and it adds two different tag types, but something must be wrong with my controller because only one of the tag types works (the regular tags — 'series' doesn't work). When I say 'doesn't work' I mean the tags on the show page are clickable links that filter my index page down to only those artworks that have the tag that I linked from: this works for 'tags' but not for 'series.' Series just shows me all the artworks, instead of only the ones with the series tag that I linked from.

Controller: not very DRY! suggestions welcome. :)

```
def index
    if params[:tag]
      @artworks = Artwork.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @artworks = Artwork.all
    end
  end

  def tagged
    if params[:tag].present? 
      @artworks = Artwork.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else 
      @artworks = Artwork.all
    end  
  end

  def series
    if params[:series].present? 
      @artworks = Artwork.tagged_with(params[:series])
    else 
      @artworks = Artwork.all
    end  
  end
```

Strong params in control permits:

```
:tag_list, :tag, :series_list, :series
```

Model:

```
acts_as_taggable
acts_as_taggable_on :tags, :series
```

Routes:

```
get 'series' => 'artworks#index', :as => 'series'
get 'tagged' => 'artworks#index', :as => 'tagged'
root "artworks#index"
```

Show:

```
<% unless @artwork.series.blank? %>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <p class="field-label">Series</p>
    <% @artwork.series.each do |series| %>
      <span class="tags">
        <%= link_to series.name, series_url(:series => series.name) %>
      </span>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% unless @artwork.tags.blank? %>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <p class="field-label">Tags</p>
    <% @artwork.tags.each do |tag| %>
      <span class="tags">
        <%= link_to tag.name, tagged_url(:tag => tag.name) %>
      </span>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Index:

```
<div id="artworks" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @artworks.each do |artwork| %>
    <div class="box">
        <%= link_to image_tag(artwork.image.url(:medium)), artwork %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this to work. Here's what I did in my controller that made things work:

```
def index
    if params[:tag] 
      @artworks = Artwork.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    elsif params[:series]
      @artworks = Artwork.tagged_with(params[:series])
    else
      @artworks = Artwork.all
    end
  end

  def tagged
      @artworks = Artwork.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  end

  def series
      @artworks = Artwork.tagged_with(params[:series]) 
  end
```

Comment: BTW [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/ruby/ruby-if-else-if-command-syntax/) helped me figure out that I should use elsif instead of else if