# Acts_as_taggable_on tag names as Thinking Sphinx attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx, acts-as-taggable-on

My model is indexed with Thinking Sphinx and I am wanting to filter search results by the model's tags—provided by acts_as_taggable_on. I read [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082399/thinking-sphinx-and-acts-as-taggable-on-plugin), which enabled my searches to use `:conditions => { :tags => 'Comedy' }` as a filtering query.

This is not a catch-all solution, since by default all text is searched in Sphinx's indexed fields. For example, when I search `Model.search :conditions => { :tags => "Comedy" }`, results with the tag `Black Comedy` also appear. I see that using attributes instead of fields is a solution, but I cannot seem to get valid results when searching `Model.search :with => { :tags => "Comedy" }` and my `define_index` block looks like this:

```
define_index
   indexes title, :sortable => true
   has category_tags(:name), :as => :tags
end
```

Note that I am building upon the previous answer provided in the question linked above. The answerer details indexing tags within context—thus the reason for the category_tags method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your index to:

```
define_index
  indexes title, :sortable => true
  has "CRC32(category_tags.name)", :as => :tags, :type => integer
end
```

Note: category_tags.name refers to your_table_name.column_name

And search the tag after converting to int:

```
Model.search :with => {:tags =>'Comedy'.to_crc32}
```

See common questions for more: http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/common_issues.html